# Not able to connect using IPV6 address using Jsch

Tags: ipv6, jsch

```
>>> from com.jcraft.jsch import JSchException
>>> from com.jcraft.jsch import JSch
>>> jsch=JSch()
>>> jsch.setKnownHosts("/Users/riteshagarwal/.ssh/known_hosts");
>>> session=jsch.getSession("root", "fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0010", 22);
>>> session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
>>> session.setPassword("password")
>>> session.connect();
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
>>>
```

Jsch version used on 0.1.54.
I am able to ssh/ping this IP and this is a local vagrant machine. But not able to succeed. Help is much appreciated.

I tried without giving the known_hosts and StrictHostKeyChecking as No but that also didn't worked.

Comment: Can you do `new Socket("fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0010", 22)` in Java?

Comment: Thanks for replying Martin. I want to do file transfers, run commands on remote linux machine and stuff like that. Can it be done through Socket?

Comment: The `fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0010` address is in the Reserved part of the ULA addressing. While `fc00::/7` is the ULA address range, the first half of the range (`fc00::/8`) is reserved for a global authority to assign. The second half of the range (`fd00::/8`) is available for local assignment, but the next 40 bits must be randomly chosen. See _[RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193)_ for the details.

Comment: Ron, but I can use these addresses in my local private network. Please correct me if i am wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: We understand that. But JSch ultimately does `new Socket("fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0010", 22)` - If that does not work, you won't be able to use JSch. At least not without modification.